# ios app user authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to Xcode and Objective-C. I need to create a login functionality for my iOS application. When anyone enters the username and password in the respective fields and taps on login, the application should communicate with a sqlite database which holds username and password. If the username, password pair matches with the entry in the database, the user should be able to proceed to the next page, else a proper error message should be displayed.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? SQLite? Alert views? String comparison? Storyboard segues? Please specify your problem. "Implement the functionality" is currently the answer to your question.

Comment: it is a nice homework. :)

Comment: Implementing with THIS approach will lead you nowhere. May be you will be provided answer here; But, that won't make you PROGRAMMER. I suggest you try some basic tutorials as some site and learn on things are done. If you find some specific question by then; don't hesitate to post it over here. I hope you are getting my point.

Comment: Where is this SQLite database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a method which returns `boolean` result.
2. Create a query which checks the username & password entered by user in your database.
3. If username and password matches, then method returns `true` else returns `false`.
4. If `true`, move user to your next screen after login else show `alert` for invalid credentials.

   ```
   -(BOOL)validateUser
   {
       [self openDatabase];

       BOOL isValid = FALSE;

       sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;


       const char *sql ="select UserId from MstUser where Username = ? and Password = ?";

       if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(mainDatabase, sql , -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
       {
           sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [txtUsername UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
           sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, [txtPasswrod UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
           while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW )
           {
               isValid = True;
               int userId = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);
           }
       }
       else
       {
           NSLog(@"Error : -------'%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(mainDatabase));
       }

       sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
       sqlite3_close(mainDatabase);
       compiledStatement = nil;

       return isValid;
   }

   if ([self validateUser])
   {
       //Login user
   }
   else 
   {
       //alert to show invalid user
   }
   ```

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.

Comment: P.S. This teaches bad security practices (i.e. storing a naked password in a database...)

Comment: @borrrden it is just a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

[SDLoginKit](https://github.com/stevederico/SDLoginKit) might be a good start.